# Is it possible to delete all keys on an AWS ElastiCache redis cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cli

I'm trying to delete all keys/values in an AWS ElastiCache cluster, but when I'm executing `flushall` or `flushdb` from redis-cli, it only removes the values in the node I'm currently connected to.

I am looking for one command which can delete all keys from all nodes in a cluster. I can run `cluster nodes`, get the list of master nodes, connect to each master node separately, *then* run `flushdb`, but that seems like a lot of overhead to call what's effectively a `TRUNCATE` command. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Drop Database database_name, this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

https://costimuraru.wordpress.com/2017/11/14/delete-keys-from-aws-elasticache-redis/
This link can help.
Try deleting using redis-cli by connecting to aws elasti cache redis as described and see it works